# How to auto pip install all modules not found?

Tags: python, pip

If you have python project without the requirements.txt - you might need to run the project, check the ModuleNotFoundError , install the module , repeat.

How can all the missing modules be installed at once?

Comment: I think it's impossible because of Python can't raise all exceptions ModuleNotFoundError. Its start from the first point and begin to import module - if it doesn't exist an exception will be raised and you script will be losed

Answer (score 7):

This is mostly a problem with whoever is managing the project requirements. To my knowledge, no easy solution exists. A workaround is to use grep to find and examine imports manually. It's gross but it works.

```
grep -r --include=\*.py 'import' YOUR_DIR
```

Ok now I'm shamelessly building on @perplexabot's answer, which will ignore local module level imports and filter out non top-level third-party imports:

```
grep -hEr --include=\*.py '^import|^from' <path/to/dir> | cut -d' ' -f2 | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | sort -u -t' ' | grep -v <path/to/dir> > requirements.txt
```

Comment: It's to strip out local imports, `-v` directs grep to print all lines not containing a pattern.

Comment: I understand what `grep -v`  does but I don't understand what it is doing in this context. I don't see a pattern arg for it. Running that command verbatim results in an empty output (after replacing `<path/to/dir>` and `YOUR_DIR` with the same dir). Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: `YOUR_DIR` doesn't exist in the second command, as I was building upon your reply. If one replaces both instances of <path/to/dir> in the second command the grep -v does a final step of filtering out your local package itself.

If your local package was my_package, the final output will be

  `argparse`
  `my_package`
  `requests`

without using the final grep -v, given there are any local imports within my_package.

Comment: I like your solution, but I don't think the last `grep` should be there. Testing that command on a populated directory results in an empty output. Removing the last `grep` works for me. Maybe it is OS/machine differences, regardless, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Shamelessly building on top of @NateDellinger 's answer. Use this to create a requirements.txt file:

```
grep -hEr --include=\*.py '^import|^from' <path/to/dir> | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort -u > requirements.txt
```

Then do a `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Haha, that's pretty great. Still requires a bit of manual curation though as it will include both internal package imports and non-top level third-party imports. For fun I ran it on one of my projects and got things like `werkzeug.exceptions`. I imagine with a little extra work you could trim out non-top level imports and exclude imports under `<path/to/dir>` :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just assumed pip will ignore these entries (the internal packages you speak of). I didn't test tho.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to using `grep` is to use a python package called `findimports`, which will print out all the dependencies.

```
findimports -n <PATH_TO_DIR>
```

Answer (score 0):

a hacky python solution :D

```
import re
import pip

pkgs = [] 
with open('file_you_want_to_run.py') as f:
    for lines in f:
        pkgs.append(re.sub('import\s|from\s|[*]|\s','',lines)) #strips the package names, deletes import, from and any * entries


pip.main(['install'] + pkgs) #might be slightly different for your version of pip..i.e. pip._internal.main or something similar
```